# MacOS opendirectoryd Constantly Running Taking Up CPU

Tags: macos, cpu

recently I found that my mac has been running hot even when left idle. I looked into the activity monitor and it seems like there is a daemon opendirectoryd that has been constantly running and taking up around 10% CPU.

[image]

After further inspection, I found in the console that opendirectoryd is doing some kind of authentication repeatedly.

[image]

I am not an expert in MacOS so I am hoping someone could help me identify that is triggering opendirectoryd or how I can stop this behaviour.

This is an intel Mac currently running MacOS 12.0.1. However, I have noticed this problem in Big Sur, and I upgraded to Monterey in hope that it could solve the issue. Please let me know if I can provide any further information to help find the issue.